# Gridstack not updating on delete

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach, gridstack

Here is my example of Gridstack layout that uses Knockout bindings. The problem is that my view doesn't get updated based on the model, when it should.

After pressing `Delete me` the console output shows that the `widgets` observable array gets updated correctly, while the view doesn't. The cause seems to be on this line (which is not being called):

```
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(item, function () { 
    self.grid.removeWidget(item); 
});
```

As far as I know, the `foreach` binding should update automatically, why it doesn't?

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.grid = null;
  self.widgets = ko.observableArray([{
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 1,
    height: 1
  }, {
    x: 0,
    y: 1,
    width: 1,
    height: 1
  }]);
  self.deleteWidget = function(item) {
    console.log("widgets before", self.widgets());
    self.widgets.remove(item);
    console.log("widgets after", self.widgets());
    return false;
  };
  self.afterAddWidget = function(items) {
    if (self.grid == null) {
      self.grid = $('.grid-stack').gridstack({
        auto: false
      }).data('gridstack');
    }
    var item = _.find(items, function(i) {
      return i.nodeType == 1
    });
    self.grid.addWidget(item);
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(item, function() {
      self.grid.removeWidget(item);
    });
  };
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
.grid-stack {
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
.grid-stack-item-content {
  color: #2c3e50;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #18bc9c;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/troolee/gridstack.js/master/dist/gridstack.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/troolee/gridstack.js/master/dist/gridstack.js"></script>

<div class="grid-stack" data-bind="foreach: {data: widgets, afterRender: afterAddWidget}">
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-bind="attr: {'data-gs-x': $data.x, 'data-gs-y': $data.y, 'data-gs-width': $data.width, 'data-gs-height': $data.height, 'data-gs-auto-position': $data.auto_position}">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content">
      <button data-bind="click: $root.deleteWidget">Delete me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gridstack is a DOM-controlling widget. You need some kind of binding handler to make Knockout play nicely with DOM-controlling widgets.

It looks like maybe you're working from [this example](http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/demo/knockout.html). It uses components in a way that is sort of a built-in binding handler. It seems to work, but I recommend putting DOM-manipulation where it goes: in the binding handlers.

**Update**: Here is your example with the gridstack code put into a binding handler. It simply wraps a `foreach` binding handler and adds the `afterRender` option to it in the update. Now the viewmodel looks like a viewmodel, and you would be able to handle multiple gridstacks on a page without `$(.grid-stack)` picking the wrong one.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.gridstack = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context);

    return {
      controlsDescendantBindings: true
    };
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    var widgets = valueAccessor(),
      grid = $(element).gridstack().data('gridstack'),
      afterAddWidget = function(items) {
        var item = _.find(items, function(i) {
          return i.nodeType === 1;
        });
        grid.addWidget(item);
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(item, function() {
          grid.removeWidget(item);
        });
      },
      newVA = function() {
        return {
          data: widgets,
          afterRender: afterAddWidget
        };
      };
    ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, newVA, allBindingsAccessor, data, context);
  }
};

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.grid = null;
  self.widgets = ko.observableArray([{
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 1,
    height: 1
  }, {
    x: 0,
    y: 1,
    width: 1,
    height: 1
  }]);
  self.deleteWidget = function(item) {
    self.widgets.remove(item);
  };
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
.grid-stack {
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
.grid-stack-item-content {
  color: #2c3e50;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #18bc9c;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/troolee/gridstack.js/master/dist/gridstack.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/troolee/gridstack.js/master/dist/gridstack.js"></script>

<div class="grid-stack" data-bind="gridstack: widgets">
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-bind="attr: {'data-gs-x': $data.x, 'data-gs-y': $data.y, 'data-gs-width': $data.width, 'data-gs-height': $data.height, 'data-gs-auto-position': $data.auto_position}">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content">
      <button data-bind="click: $parent.deleteWidget">Delete me</button>
    </div>
  </div></div><!-- <---- NO SPACE BETWEEN THESE CLOSING TAGS -->
```

Comment: You are probably referring to this part: `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(item, function () { self.grid.removeWidget(item); });` Although it's present in my example, the call to `self.grid.removeWidget(item);` isn't made. Now I'd rather focus on a quick way to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not referring to a part. I'm talking about proper structure in Knockout programming. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was actually caused by an extra space character between `</div>` closing tags. The [example](http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/demo/knockout.html) warns about that. In my case it was inserted automatically by the code formatter, so it went unnoticed. The line in the HTML template should be `</div></div><!-- <---- NO SPACE BETWEEN THESE CLOSING TAGS -->` with **NO space between the `</div></div>`**

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.grid = null;
  self.widgets = ko.observableArray([{
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 1,
    height: 1
  }, {
    x: 0,
    y: 1,
    width: 1,
    height: 1
  }]);
  self.deleteWidget = function(item) {
    console.log("widgets before", self.widgets());
    self.widgets.remove(item);
    console.log("widgets after", self.widgets());
    return false;
  };
  self.afterAddWidget = function(items) {
    if (self.grid == null) {
      self.grid = $('.grid-stack').gridstack({
        auto: false
      }).data('gridstack');
    }
    var item = _.find(items, function(i) {
      return i.nodeType == 1
    });
    self.grid.addWidget(item);
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(item, function() {
      self.grid.removeWidget(item);
    });
  };
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
.grid-stack {
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
.grid-stack-item-content {
  color: #2c3e50;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #18bc9c;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/troolee/gridstack.js/master/dist/gridstack.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/troolee/gridstack.js/master/dist/gridstack.js"></script>

<div class="grid-stack" data-bind="foreach: {data: widgets, afterRender: afterAddWidget}">
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-bind="attr: {'data-gs-x': $data.x, 'data-gs-y': $data.y, 'data-gs-width': $data.width, 'data-gs-height': $data.height, 'data-gs-auto-position': $data.auto_position}">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content">
      <button data-bind="click: $root.deleteWidget">Delete me</button>
    </div>
  </div></div><!-- <---- NO SPACE BETWEEN THESE CLOSING TAGS -->
```